# How to print datetime in user defined format in c++ windows console app?

Tags: c++, windows, datetime, format, console-application

what is the easiest way to print system datetime in user-defined format? User defines his format as input string which I store into buffer and then I need to print datetime according to that format into the console. I'm writing c++ console application under windows and cannot find any function which would do that in simple way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Windows offers the API functions [GetTimeFormat(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd318130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[GetDateFormat(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd318086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetTimeFormatEx(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd318131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[GetDatFormatEx(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd318088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this job. Here is a small example:

```
SYSTEMTIME t;
int result;
char buffer[1024];


GetLocalTime(&t);

result = GetTimeFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
                       0,
                       &t,
                       "hh:mm:ss",
                       (LPTSTR)buffer,
                       sizeof(buffer));
if (result > 0)
{
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

result = GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
                       0,
                       &t,
                       "dd MMM yy",
                       (LPTSTR)buffer,
                       sizeof(buffer));
if (result > 0)
{
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

The output is:

```
07:15:35
17 Nov 14
```